# Trouble configuring Django with AWS/ElasticIP

Tags: django, amazon-ec2

I am trying to attach my domain to my Django app on AWS.

The first thing I did was get the app working and accessible from the IPv4 Public IP supplied by AWS. This, of course, involved updating my NGINX and DJANGO  configurations. No problems there.

I followed directions from 2 websites about attaching my domain. Both said to set up an elasticIP. This seems to work fine till I use the NEW public IP address to access my site. Then I start getting BAD REQUEST 400.

I tried updating my NGINX and DJANGO configurations to both the NEW public IP and the private IP that is now available, neither works.

How should I configure the NGINX and DJANGO configurations after setting up an elastic IP so that I can test it by calling AN IP ADDRESS? Should I be using something different than the NEW public IP or private IP supplied?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure the ALLOWED_HOSTS has your IP  at settings.py

Reference

https://blog.anvileight.com/posts/how-to-fix-bad-request-400-in-django/

Comment: Thanks. But this is the question really, which IP address should be used? I've tried the new public IP created as well as the private IP. Everything worked fine BEFORE i started working with the elastic IP, so  I can only assume the issue is about which IP's to use in DJANGO and NGINX.

Comment: csn you first set it to ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] to verify the issue and restart

Comment: Thanks. I did that, it worked. Then I changed it back to the public address, and it is still working. Possibly some change in my restarting process. Not sure. But both the IP  and domain name work properly now.

Comment: ok Awesome, glad to help, can you mark the question as solved and vote for the answer.